# Filtering without using a global object

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a datatable that is sometimes shown and sometimes hidden.  I also have several other tables on the same page.

The datatables example [(located here)](https://datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/range_filtering.html) uses a global object to store your custom function `$.fn.dataTable.ext.search`.  This is great, but it affects all tables.

I can't find a way to provide a search function *per table* and not add it to a global variable.

Here is what I have so far:

```
t.rows().data().filter(
  function(val, idx){ 
    console.log("Value: " + JSON.stringify(val) + " at " + idx); 
    if(idx < 2) {return true;} return false;
  })
```

This works, but how do I then redraw the table with my new rows?  Calling t.draw() does not work, so what next?

This is the old question before the edit:

Here's my initial code for the filter, which runs and prints what I expect, but I cannot isolate it to run only on one table on the page.  I cannot tell which table it is inside the function (I don't think) but I really only want the function to be called on a certain table.

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
    function(settings, data, dataIndex ) 
    { 
        console.log(settings); 
        console.log(data); 
        console.log(dataIndex); 
    });
```

Comment: I've added a code sample, it's really very simple in concept, I just need to be able to indicate which tables I want it to work with and which to ignore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first parameter you receive from the search function is the [`settings`](https://datatables.net/reference/type/DataTables.Settings) variable, which contains the full configuration and data of a DataTable. With that, you can access the table's [API](https://datatables.net/reference/api/).

Then you can use [`table().node()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/table%28%29.node%28%29) to reach the tag's node (it returns the table's DOM element):

```js
var tablesToSearchArray = new Array("example2");

$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(function(settings, data, dataIndex) {
    var api = new $.fn.dataTable.Api( settings );
    var tableId = api.table().node().id;

    if (tablesToSearchArray.indexOf(tableId) === -1) {
        return true; // don't filter this table.
    }

    var min = parseInt($('#min').val(), 10);
    var max = parseInt($('#max').val(), 10);
    var age = parseFloat(data[3]) || 0; // use data for the age column

    if ( ( isNaN( min ) && isNaN( max ) ) ||
         ( isNaN( min ) && age <= max ) ||
         ( min <= age   && isNaN( max ) ) ||
         ( min <= age   && age <= max ) )
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable();
    var table2 = $('#example2').DataTable();

    $('#min, #max').keyup(function() {
        table.draw();
        table2.draw(); // just so you see it won't filter
    });
});
```

This was based on the [example](https://datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/range_filtering.html) at the DataTables site. Check out the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a2dqmfk9/).

Comment: Take a look at my edit, I would like to use something like that, but I cannot figure out how to make the rows hid e or show.  I can get the ones I want...

Comment: I have edited my answer to provide a better example, and included a JSFiddle. See if this is what you needed.

Comment: Alright, this is outstanding.  The DataTables API seems like there should be a way to attach this filter to a single table, but if this is the way to do it so be it.  I find it weird that I can filter rows but then not do anything with them as in my example, but you get the points.

Comment: Glad it worked for you! I'd suggest that you rollback your last edit to revision 2 (click "edited x mins ago", link "rollback" on 2nd revision), as that text was much clearer and may be better for people looking into this in the future.